# Ограничение количества нажатий по гиперссылке на сайте

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка HTML сайта которая использует файл с кодом для Java Script, который позволяет ограничить количество нажатий до 3:

JS код:

```
var count = 0;

function myfns(){

count++;

console.log(count);

if (count>3){

document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;

alert("You can only click this button 3 times !!!");

}


}
```

HTML кнопка:

```
<button id="btn" onclick="myfns()">Click Me</button>
```

Код позволяет каждому пользователю нажать на кнопку 3 раза и отключает ее.

Как переделать код так, чтобы он ограничивал количество нажатий для всех пользователей, а не для каждого? (Один пользователь после нажатия оставляет для других возможность нажать на кнопку только 2 раза)

Возможно ли переделать его под гиперссылку установленную на изображение, которое используется как кнопка?

Comment: используя только фронт - это сделать не получится
если подключить бэк, то нужно отдавать текущий `count`, который храниться в бд к примеру, для всех посетителей, как вариант это делать запрос с фронта на бэк при загрузке страницы, получать `count` и уже проверять его

Comment: Я так и предполагал. Есть пример как это сделать?

Comment: Берёте и пишите backend, можете загуглить fullstack app и там разберётесь)

Comment: Спасибо. #ryzen

Comment: Буду рад если кто-нибудь уточнит код для проверки count.